# Passing a function with array parameter as a parameter to another function

Tags: arrays, c, function, pointers

I am trying to calculate the Jacobian matrix (numerical, at a given point) of a given equation. Now, I don't know the dimension of the equation beforehand, so I can't just do something like

```
static double f(double x1, x2)
{
    return x1 * x1 - 2 * x1 * x2;
}
```

so instead, I am getting the input values as an array like so

```
static double f(double xArray[]) 
{
    return xArray[0] * xArray[0] - 2 * xArray[1] * xArray[0];
}

void jacobian(double xArray[], double jacob_matrix, size_t size,
        double f(double xArray[], size_t)) 
{
    // calculations
}
```

However, when I try to call the function from `main` like

```
int main(void)
{
    double x_input[4] = {1., 1., 3., 4.};
    double jacob_matrix[4]; 
    
    jacobian(x_input, jacob_matrix, 4, f(x_input, 4));
    return 0;
}
```

I get `incompatible type for argument 4 of 'jacobian'` I imagine this has to do with my array being casted into a pointer, but I can't figure out how to fix this.

Comment: Learn about function pointers and how to use them, that's what you probably want to do.

Comment: please add the definition of `f` function

Comment: @kiner_shah Apparently that's what I was missing.
@tstanisl I must've added in the second snippet with `static double f...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the function signature:

```
void jacobian(double xArray[], double jacob_matrix, size_t size,
    double f(double xArray[], size_t))
```

For the second argument, if you're going to pass an array you need the argument to be a pointer, `double* jacob_matrix` or `double jacob_matrix[]`.

For the 4th argument, the passed function arguments should match the caller signature, so in your case you are passing a function which is of type `double (*)(double *)`, but the caller expects a function of type `double (*)(double *, size_t)`, so one of them should be changed to match, either add a second argument to the called function, or remove the second argument of the caller function signature.

```
#include <stdio.h>

static double f(double xArray[]) 
{
    return xArray[0] * xArray[0] - 2 * xArray[1] * xArray[0];
}

void jacobian(double xArray[], double* jacob_matrix, size_t size,
        double f(double xArray[])) 
{   
    printf("%f", f(xArray)); // for example
}

int main(void)
{
    double x_input[4] = {1., 1., 3., 4.};
    double jacob_matrix[4]; 
    
    jacobian(x_input, jacob_matrix, 4, f);
    return 0;
}
```

Note that my approach only addresses the code correctness and not the mathematical part, *i.e.* the jacobian calculation.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer! I was wondering, normally when we are passing a function as a parameter, we can do `void jacob(double f(double x))` when x is of type double. In the case of pointer, can we just use the function signature as ```void jacobian(double xArray[], double* jacob_matrix, size_t size,
    double f(double* )) ```

But I guess in this case, then `f` cannot match its input argument with `x_input`.

Comment: Using a `typedef` for the function type would increase readability.

Comment: @ofey, I'm not sure I understand your doubt, but  `x_input` is passed correctly, an array passed as argument of a function will decay to a pointer to its first element, so it is correct.

Comment: @ofey as for the function argument, the passed function arguments should match the caller signature, so in your case you are passing a function which is of type `double (*)(double *)`, but the caller expects a function of type `double (*)(double *, size_t)`, so one of them should be changed to match, either add a second argument to the called function, or remove the second argument of the caller function signature.

Comment: @anastaciu What I mean is that, I think `void foo(double bar(double, double))` is OK, so in the case `bar` takes two arrays, we can simply write `void foo(double bar(double*, double*))`. Am I correct on this?

Comment: @ofey, yes, you can pass two arrays to a function with that signature.

Comment: @anastaciu Great! Then, let's say my function signature was `void jacobian(double xArray[], double* jacob_matrix, size_t size, double f(double*))`. In that case, if I were to call `jacobian(x_input, jacob_matrix, 4, f);`, how would `f` know which pointer it takes?

Comment: @ofey, you need to do it yourself, you're only passing a function, for example `void jacobian(double xArray[], double* jacob_matrix, size_t size, double f(double xArray[])) 
{
    double a[] = {5};
    printf("%f", f(a));
}
`

Answer (score 2):

You need to pass the function pointer to `f`, not the result of calling `f`.
Try:

```
jacobian(x_input, jacob_matrix, 4, f);
```

Comment: Thanks. That seems to work. I only have to change how I call `jacobian`, not its arguments I suppose? Does `f` choose its input array to be `xArray` because of 
`
void jacobian(double xArray[], double jacob_matrix, size_t size, double f(double xArray[], size_t)) 
` ?

Comment: @ofey, parameter `jacob_matrix` is a scalar of type `double`. Probably you would like to change it to `double jacob_matrix[]`.

Comment: Ah sorry. The original code was on another computer, so I was manually typing it. In my original implementation, `jacob_matrix` is as you've suggested.